# Powershell: Use specific data from a Get-NetAdapter results as a variable in Powershell ISE

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to use ifIndex result for a specific network adapter in another powershell command. How would I create a line to pull that specific adapter's ifIndex?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this:

`$ifIndexVariable = Get-NetAdapter -Name 'Specific Adapter Name' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'ifIndex'`

Comment: Terribly sorry for verbose answer. Attracts downvotes as it seems.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will get your adapter and select the `IfIndex` property

```
(get-netadapter -name "AdapterNameHere").IfIndex
```